# Repeating numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 3D np arrays like this :

```
 x= array([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],
    [  4.,   5.,   6.],
    [  7.,   8.,   9.],
    [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

   [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
    [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
    [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
    [ 22.,  23.,  24.]]])
```

I would like to repeat my array n times ( eg 3 times) like this :

```
array([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],
    [  4.,   5.,   6.],
    [  7.,   8.,   9.],
    [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

   [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
    [  4.,   5.,   6.],
    [  7.,   8.,   9.],
    [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

   [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
    [  4.,   5.,   6.],
    [  7.,   8.,   9.],
    [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

   [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
    [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
    [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
    [ 22.,  23.,  24.]],

    [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
    [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
    [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
    [ 22.,  23.,  24.]]

   [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
    [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
    [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
    [ 22.,  23.,  24.]]])
```

I have tried like this :

```
xx=np.vstack([x]*3)
print xx.reshape(6,4,3)


array([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],
    [  4.,   5.,   6.],
    [  7.,   8.,   9.],
    [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

   [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
    [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
    [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
    [ 22.,  23.,  24.]],

   [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
    [  4.,   5.,   6.],
    [  7.,   8.,   9.],
    [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

   [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
    [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
    [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
    [ 22.,  23.,  24.]],

   [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
    [  4.,   5.,   6.],
    [  7.,   8.,   9.],
    [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

   [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
    [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
    [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
    [ 22.,  23.,  24.]]])
```

How can I get in the order what I want, there should be the easy way to do this. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of trial and error I have found a way to do it:

```
np.tile(x.reshape(2,12), [1,3]).reshape(6,4,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.repeat` with `axis = 0`:

```
np.repeat(x, [3, 3], axis = 0)  # or more generally np.repeat(x, [n] * len(x), axis = 0)
                                # here n is the repeat times
Out[514]:
array([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.],
        [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

       [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.],
        [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

       [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.],
        [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

       [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
        [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
        [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
        [ 22.,  23.,  24.]],

       [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
        [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
        [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
        [ 22.,  23.,  24.]],

       [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
        [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
        [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
        [ 22.,  23.,  24.]]])
```

---

Another option would be to index it as:

```
x[[0,0,0,1,1,1]]
```

Or programmatically:

```
x[[i for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(3)]]
Out[518]:
array([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.],
        [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

       [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.],
        [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

       [[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.],
        [ 10.,  11.,  12.]],

       [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
        [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
        [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
        [ 22.,  23.,  24.]],

       [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
        [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
        [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
        [ 22.,  23.,  24.]],

       [[ 13.,  14.,  15.],
        [ 16.,  17.,  18.],
        [ 19.,  20.,  21.],
        [ 22.,  23.,  24.]]])
```

Comment: Starting with a (2,4,3) you shouldn't need the reshape after repeat.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the comment. It works with `[3,3]` along `axis = 0` without reshape.